# How to replace range value by each with multiple command

Tags: vim

#### HTML

```
$row['name'];
$row['age'];
$row['nickname'];
```

I want to make it like

```
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nickname']; ?></td>
```

I user V to select the area, and type `s/^/<td><?php echo /g`, it will success replace the head part, but if I want to do it in one line like `s/^/<td><?php echo /g | s/$/; ?><\/td>/g` to replace both head and tail, it will failed, it's reasonable, is it possible to replace both head and tail by each line at one time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "replace" part, you can use `&` to insert the whole match so you don't need two substitutions, here; one is enough:

```
:s/.*/<td><?php echo & ?><\/td>
```

See `:help sub-replace-special` for other useful atoms to use in the replace part.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Select the lines in visual mode and use the command

```
:'<,'>s/^\(.*\)$/<td><?php echo \1 ?><\/td>/
```